# Replace specific elements in NumPy array with random characters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array that looks like this:

```
array(['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '1', '1', '_', '_',
       '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '1', '1', '1',
       '1', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_',
       '_', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'e', '_',
       '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_',
       '_', '_', '_'], dtype='<U1')
```

I'm looking for a way to replace the `"_"` characters with random choices from the ascii lowercase, digits, and punctuation characters:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

Note that I'm trying to get a different random character for each element, while preserving the non `"_"` characters as they are. I've tried this:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
chars = string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits+string.punctuation
array[array=="_"] = chars[rng.choice(68,1)[0]]
```

but it gives the same random character each time. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: That is because you set your random seed to the same number, please look in to: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html

Comment: I try the same without seeding and it doesn't make a difference... The problem seems to be the construction in the final line, which only creates a single character number and then sets all the elements of the array to that character, but I'm not sure what I can do differently.

Comment: @3DspatialUser I don't think that's the problem, the problem is that only one random character is being requested: in `rng.choice(68, 1)` the second argument `1` is number of samples

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code only generates a single random character! In `rng.choice(68, 1)`, the second argument `1` is the size of the sample to generate.

To fix this, you need to generate as many random characters as you need:

```py
# convert chars to a numpy array
char_array = np.fromiter(chars, dtype=array.dtype)

# count how many characters you need to generate
size = (array == "_").sum()

# sample chars
random_chars = rng.choice(char_array, size)

# replace "_" in array
array[array == "_"] = random_chars
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I got the following error when running the third line: `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`, but it seems to work when changed to `random_chars = rng.choice(char_array,size)`

Comment: @celery_gemini thanks you are right, I've corrected my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
random_chars = np.array(list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"))
array[array=="_"] = np.random.choice(random_chars, replace=False, size=(array=="_").sum())
```